# This Python function removes an unexpected value from the list, not at the index position expected - nested index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, return

I'm doing a course of study and this is part of a question in one of the modules.  It asks for the expected result.

```
list = [x * x for x in range(5)]

def fun(lst):
    del lst[lst[2]]
    return lst

print(fun(list))
```

I have been on to pythontutor.com to see what the code is doing and something odd happens, I'm certain it is due to the line:

```
del lst[lst[2]]
```

the first line (list comprehension) creates the list containing [0, 1, 4, 9, 16], then the functions deletes lst[lst[2]], which removes value 16 from the list at index 4.  I expected it to remove the value 4 at index 2.

If I change the line to:

```
del lst[2]
```

this does remove the value 4 at index 2, so I suppose what I need to understand is what is happening when the line has the list 'nested' ( del lst[lst[2] ) as in the original code.  I don't get why it removes the 16 in that case.

Comment: How is list[2] 4 please?

Comment: You missed the indirection. The list is `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]`. The value at index 2 is `4`. But you don't call `del lst[2]`, you call `del lst[lst[2]]`. As `lst[2]` has the value `4` this is the same as `del lst[4]` and that's the last value of your list.

Comment: I agree about not using built-ins as variable names!  Would you believe it but this is code I copied straight from a question on The Python Institute's PCAP course?!  

the list comprehension line produces [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]

The only part of the syntax I don't get is why the del line removes the 16 value at index 4, rather than the 4 value at index 2.  I'm told in some replies below that:

del lst[lst[2]] is equivalent to del lst[4], but no one has explained *why* this is the case.

Also, what is the value of writing the longer version over the shorter one?

Comment: I changed my previous comment. Please check it again.

Comment: I get it now!  I'm deleting from the index position which matches the number of the value of list at index 2!  Got you.. Thanks and apologies for any facepalms caused by my density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you have written this code `del lst[lst[2]]`. Lets just focus on the `lst[2]` which is inside of `lst[...]`. Here, `lst[2]` is asking for the second index of lst then the second index of lst is 4 as the for loop created. then the `lst[2]` inside `lst[...]` becomes 4. 
So, at the end it becomes like this:
`lst[4] # As the lst[2] is 4 which is generated through loop`


So, at the end it removes the 16 which is ate the index no. 4.

Hopefully, you understood.

Comment: Thanks @Kodi Learn.  I *did* get it in the end, but your explanation is great.  I suppose, because I'm so new to this Python and programming in general), I didn't realise that it could do that.  It's handy to know.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lst` is

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
 ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
 0  1  2  3  4  <--indexes
```

Hopefully you can see that `lst[2]` is equal to 4, so

```
del lst[lst[2]]
```

is equivalent to

```
del lst[4]
```

which removes the element at index 4 (which is the 16).

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you:
You wrote this code:

```
del lst[lst[2]]
```

So, let me go to step by step.
There you wrote lst[2] inside lst[]. the index of lst at 2 is 4 so it means like this if we shorten:

```
lst[4]
```

So, it was removing 16 from list which is at index 4

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how list[2] inside list becomes 4?  Does it automatically double the index value?  I'm trying to understand the technical mechanics of it.